# XAML Binding: binding to properties of a "global" object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I would like to have one (global, singleton) object in my application that exposes a number of dependency properties. I would like to bind values in XAML to these dependency properties. How can I achieve this so that the syntax of my XAML binding is as simple as possible (in other words, not constantly worrying about RelativeSource, AncestoryType, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) markup extension to bind directly to your Singleton, as it's a static property.

For example, if your singleton had a property named "Foo":

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static local:YourSingleton.Instance.Foo}" />
```

Comment: This seems promising. What's the syntax look like when YourSingleton is in a different namespace than your xaml?

Comment: @anthony It's the same - the "local" is whatever you setup in your xmlns at the top of the xaml to map the namespace to a prefix.

Comment: Even after doing that i always get an error: "Cannot find the type 'YourSingleton'"

Comment: @anthony: You can edit your question, if you want - show the binding, xmlns section, and your singleton type with namespace... there's probably just something missing in there.